# 'Error opening terminal: unknown.' error when running a command in SSH server through Python

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, paramiko

I am trying to SSH to a server with Python and I have been able to do so successfully. I am able to run the commands within Python successfully with one exception, the main command that is the focus of my program. It is a SIPp command that will only run within the SSH server and in a specific folder.

When I run the command in my terminal, it works perfectly fine; however, when I connect to the SSH server through PExpect or Paramiko (both work fine), I try to send my command but I get the

> Error Opening Terminal: Unknown

I have so far, read the docs, tried using os, subprocess, and multiple different ways of connecting with Paramiko and Pxssh. The several people I work with were not able to figure it out either.

The SIPp command that I am trying to send and read the output of:

```
sipp -r 5 -m 20  -trace_msg -inf users.csv -sf register.xml -d 10000 -i [IP addresses]
# some of the command was left out for simplicity's sake
# there is no issue with the command
```

Connecting to SSH through Pxssh (PExpect):

```
from pexpect import pxssh
from getpass import getpass

try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = input('hostname: ')
    username = input('username: ')
    password = getpass("password :", None)
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('cd [location of the folder]')
    s.prompt() 
    print(s.before) 
    s.sendline('sipp -r 5 -m 20  -trace_msg -inf users.csv -sf register.xml -d 10000 -i [IP addresses]') #this is the only line that doesn't work / output anything. 
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('ls')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("Something went wrong. Try again with the correct Host Name, Username, and Password")
    print(e)
```

Connecting to SSH through Paramiko:

```
from paramiko import client
from getpass import getpass

class ssh:

    client = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        self.client = client.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        if self.client:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
            output = stdout.readlines()
            print(output, stderr.readlines())
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    prevdata = b"1"
                    while prevdata:
                        prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                        alldata += prevdata

                    print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
                    self.client.close()
        else:
            print("Connection not opened.")

connection = ssh([ssh info])


connection.sendCommand("cd [location] ; sipp -r 5 -m 20  -trace_msg -inf users.csv -sf register.xml -d 10000 -i [IP addresses]")
```

Both give me this error: Error opening terminal: unknown.

My guess is that it is not spawning an actual terminal but I can't figure out what to do at this point. Any help would be sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command needs [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator).

Either:

1. Try to find if there's a way to run the command, so that it does not require the terminal emulation. Maybe [`-bg` switch](https://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#Running+SIPp+in+background) can help.

   Possibly this was a bug in an older version of SIPP. Make sure you have the latest version. See [Startup failure when running from environment without TERM](https://github.com/sipp/sipp/issues/75).
2. Or, enable the terminal emulation (what can bring unwanted side effects). With Paramiko [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command), use its `get_pty` argument:

   ```
   stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)
   ```